# Aptana - how to browse remote site?

Tags: aptana

I've recently upgraded to Aptana  3.6.0.201407100658 and the connection icons have disappeared  from all my projects - this has happened on both my Mac and my Windows 7 PC, so I assume it is intentional.

I sued to use this feature extensively for browsing remote sites or editing files directly by FTP. What is the replacement, or how do I get this back?

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for the answer myself,  but then I figured it out.

If you go to Window->Show View  you'll see the option "Remote"

That worked for me.